# Swift4でUITableviewの表示を一番上にスクロールさせるには

Tags: swift, uitableview

Xcode 9.2(9C40b)
を使ってSwiftでUITableViewを使ってリスト表示しています。

ボタンを押すとリストの一番上にスクロール(animated: true)させて移動させたいと思っています。

```
@IBOutlet weak var ContantsTable: UITableView!

@IBAction func ToTopTable(sender: AnyObject) {
    ContantsTable.setContentOffset(CGPoint(x:0, y:-ContantsTable.contentInset.top), animated: true)
    print(ContantsTable.contentInset.top) // ・・・①
}
```

実行させるとボタンを押したらセルが半分ずつ（おおよそ）上に行くのみでした。
そして、①の結果は「0.0」

何か勘違いしているのでしょうか？検索で色々なサイトを見ているのですが、いまいち理解できておらず。
ご存知の方、対処法をご教示お願いします。

[解決]
Alamofireを使ってテーブルリストの項目を取得していますが、テーブルを一番上の指示を出したすぐにAlamofireでリストの更新を行うと、テーブルを一番上にanimetedでスクロールしている途中で止まっていたようです。
Alamofireのクロージャーの中で、テーブルの一番上の指示を出したところ解決しました。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/724892/uitableview-scroll-to-the-top

こちらを試すのがよいと思います。

Swift4なので
https://stackoverflow.com/a/46631319/1979953

引用：

```
//self.tableView.reloadData() if you want to use this line remember to put it before 
let indexPath = IndexPath(row: 0, section: 0)
self.tableView.scrollToRow(at: indexPath, at: .top, animated: true)
```

が該当します。

余談ですが、変数名を `ContantsTable`, メソッド名を`ToTopTable` にされていますが、
それぞれ `contantsTable`, `toTopTable` と頭文字を小文字にするのが一般的です。

Comment: 最初に表示されるリストが完全に見えなくなるくらい、スクロールして実行すると一番上までいきますが、最初に表示されるリストが中途半端に表示されている状態で実行すると数行上にスクロールするのみです。原因ってわかりますか？

Comment: 再現できるものがないとなんとも言えないですが、勘だとセルの高さ計算がうまくいっているようでいってない。テーブルやセルのオートレイアウトに曖昧なものがあるなどが思いつきます。

Comment: セルの高さは固定です。StoryboardからセルのRow Heightを91に、func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat { return 91 }で返すようにしています。デバックで何を見ればというものもあれば教えていただけると幸いです。

Comment: んーー　闇雲になってしまいますが、セクションヘッダーがある場合についての言及 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/724892/uitableview-scroll-to-the-top/46631319#comment71043683_35428773 などがありますので、テーブルのヘッダーやセクションヘッダーのあるなしなど（ない場合はないと明記）して質問を編集なさったほうが、より正解に近づけるかもしれないです。

Comment: http://xyk.hatenablog.com/entry/2014/09/22/193701 にある通りテーブルビューはスクロールビューの機能を使うことができる（使っている）ので、この当たりもどのようになっているか調べてみると良いような気がします（必ず正解に辿り着く確証はないですが）